# Distinguish profile user and admin user IDs / get ID of user being edited

Tags: wp-admin, users, user-meta

On the user-profile page of my site I want to allow admin role users to be able to edit specific user-meta fields of subscriber role users.

How can I distinguish between the two user IDs.

The current logged in user is the admin user

```
get_current_user(); // returns the admin role user id
```

but I need to be able to access the subscriber ID to set the meta-data

```
update_user_meta($subscriber_user_id,"name","value");
```

How can i populate the `$subscriber_user_id` value correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the "profile page", i.e. `user-edit.php` in the admin back-end, the user ID of the profile currently being edited lives in the `$user_id` global.

Hence:

```
global $user_id;
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'key', 'value' );
```

is the essence of what you are looking for.

Whether the current user is an admin needs to be checked only if you have the [`edit_users`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_users) capability assigned to roles other than admins, which by default is not the case.

If you want the admins to only be able to save the metadata for subscribers, while having users of other roles, then you will have to check the edited users role before saving, obviously.

So, for the sake of completeness, the same with both checks in place:

```
global $current_user, $user_id;

/* user object of user being edited */
$edited_user = new WP_User( $user_id );

/* verify both users roles */
if (
    in_array( 'administrator', $current_user->roles ) &&
    in_array( 'subscriber', $edited_user->roles )
) {
    update_user_meta( $edited_user->ID, 'key', 'value' );
}
```